Raspberry pi as a slave device
My task is to take control of the BIOS chip and prevent it from starting the computer system when power is applied. I want to take control of the BIOS chip and read data from it when I turn on the computer, so that it does not start the main components of the computer. There is an assumption that for this it is necessary to use the Slave mode on the Rasberry pi or use interrupts. My question is how to initialize Raspberry Pi as a Slave or how to use interrupts to read data from the BIOS chip (Master mode on Raspberry Pi is not suitable - tested)?

Please edit your question and clarify which BIOS chip you mean, respectively of which computer. The Raspberry Pi itself has no BIOS, it uses a different way of booting.

can you explain what you mean by "slave mode", and what is the "master" in such slave mode - take control of sounds like something a Master would do to a Slave (how has this terminology survived wokeness!!)

I'm sorry, but it sounds as if you have been misinformed. First, there is no BIOS in a Raspberry Pi, nor is there a general "slave mode". You should edit your question - or delete it until such time as you can formulate a reasonable question.
